# How to make an icon for Android Activity?

Tags: java, android

I can't find anywhere how to get my icon into my activity. I followed the guidelines to make all the different resolutions, now what?

Comment: Do you mean an icon for your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make icons of the appropriate dimensions and place in these locations

72 x 72px png in res/drawable-hdpi
48 x 48px png in res/drawable-mdpi
36 x 36px png in res/drawable-ldpi

Make sure they all have the same name, in the example below all would be called ic_logo.png.


Now edit AndroidManifest.xml to point to your icon.
`<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">`

Comment: What is the android:theme node?